# Initialising a struct inside an array

Tags: c, struct

Recently, I attempted the following, as a shorthand for initialising a new structure and making it the first element of an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_CARS 100

typedef struct car {
    int wheels;
    int cylinders;
    int maxSpeed;
    int canOffroad;
} Car;

int main(void) {
    Car all_cars[MAX_CARS];
    // This is nice, I would like to do something equivalent to this
    all_cars[0] = {.wheels = 4,
                   .cylinders = 8,
                   .maxSpeed = 120,
                   .canOffroad = 0};

    return 0;
}
```

This, however, throws a compiler error, saying that it expects an expression before the '{'.

Now, at first I thought I might have mis-remembered initialising structs, but this works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_CARS 100

typedef struct car {
    int wheels;
    int cylinders;
    int maxSpeed;
    int canOffroad;
} Car;

int main(void) {
    Car all_cars[MAX_CARS];
    // This is ok, but introduces a (potentially) unnecessary variable
    Car new_car = {.wheels = 4,
                   .cylinders = 8,
                   .maxSpeed = 120,
                   .canOffroad = 0};
    all_cars[0] = new_car;

    return 0;
}
```

So the problem is clearly in initialising this structure as an element of an array instead of as a variable.

Is there syntax which allows for initialising structs like this, or am I stuck initialising a new struct variable every time I want to add one to an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you attempt to *initialize* the element in the array, which is only possible when you *define* the array.

Initialization is only possible with definition.

You can however use [*compound literals*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) to create a temporary structure object that is then copied into the array element:

```
all_cars[0] = (Car) {.wheels = 4,
                     .cylinders = 8,
                     .maxSpeed = 120,
                     .canOffroad = 0};
```

Comment: When you say 'define' the array, I presume you mean 'declare' (or are those the same in this case)?

Comment: @JinanDangor There's a difference between *declare* and *define*. When you *declare* a variable you tell the compiler the variable exists somewhere. When you *define* a variable you tell the compiler "here's the variable, give it some memory". For local variables the declaration and definition usually is happening at the same place.

Comment: Here are you typecasting by the (Car) expression?

Comment: @SRK No it's a compound literal. Please see the linked reference for more details.

Comment: I guess compound literal is available in C and C++ as well.

Comment: @SRK No, it's C only, not C++.